# TRIM for SSD in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, trim

I have 4 partitions in Trusty:
on the SSD there are 3: 'boot/EFI', Swap & one mounted at / which contains all other directories except `/home`. On the HDD there is one mounted at `/home` containing `/john` (i.e. user's home directories).

I have seen various instructions (e.g. howtogeek website) for enabling TRIM. What is recommended for my setup?

Answer (score 0):

I am testing all these SSD boost options,too. If u did a fresh install, trim is automatic activated.

Btw. For other performance boosts try noatime, zswap, zchache, data=writeback and other tweaks for fstab, but not in your swap partition.

Comment: It wasn't a fresh install. I copied all files except /home to the SSD from my HDD. So I can now boot from either the SDD or the HDD if the SDD goes kaput.